# Como posso somar valores de uma tabela usando ate uma data como parâmetro?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, select

Estou tentando somar alguns valores de uma tabela levando consideração uma data no sql. Quero somar os valores ate quando atingir uma data e uma valor maior ou igual ao valor inicial.

Uma empresa de investimentos deseja calcular o payback de seus clientes ao descobrir qual será o mês em que o acumulado das operações do empreendimento equivalem ou são superiores ao investimento inicial. Por exemplo, o cliente Lucas investiu 1000$ e apenas no terceiro mês obteve o seu payback, já que a soma de todas as suas operações foi superior ao seu investimento. Por outro lado, o cliente Daniel não conseguiu atingir seu payback já que seu investimento foi de 500$ e a soma de todas as suas operações foi 230$. Você precisa mostrar o nome do cliente, o investimento inicial, qual o mês do payback e o valor do retorno (valor acumulado - valor investimento inicial). Além disso, você deve mostrar o resultado ordenado do maior para o menor retorno.

Estrutura das duas tabelas :

```
 CREATE TABLE clients (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    investment NUMERIC
);

CREATE TABLE operations (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    client_id INTEGER REFERENCES clients(id),
    month INTEGER,
    profit NUMERIC
);

INSERT INTO clients (id, name, investment) values
(1, 'Daniel', 500 ),
(2, 'Oliveira', 2000),
(3, 'Lucas', 1000);

INSERT INTO operations (id, client_id, month, profit) values
( 1,    1,  1,  230 ),
( 2,    2,  1,  1000),
( 3,    2,  2,  1000),
( 4,    3,  1,  100 ),
( 5,    3,  2,  300 ),
( 6,    3,  3,  900 ),
( 7,    3,  4,  400 );
```

Por favor peço ajuda, tentei fazer mais não consegui.

Certo, eu cheguei ate este select :

```
select c.name,
       c.investment,
       CEILING((c.investment / AVG(DISTINCT o.profit))) AS month_of_payback,
       SUM(o.profit)- c.investment as "return"
  from clients c
 inner join operations o on o.client_id = c.id  
 group by c.name,c.investment
```

Porém, esta retornando o valor 700 em vez de 300 no usuário Lucas.

Comment: *"tentei fazer mais não consegui"* e o que tentou Matheus? edite e coloque na pergunta, aqui no SOPt não desenvolvemos código nem fazemos trabalhos de escola, mas podemos te ajudar a chegar lá e tirar usas dúvidas

Comment: Editado Ricardo, agradeço.

Comment: Pesquise por window functions (analytic function) se o exercício permitir.

Comment: dei uma olhada na sua query, e tecnicamente um único select não consegue fazer um "sum" limitado com critério baseado em outra coluna. O seu problema seria algo como *"soma os profits, mas só até atingir o investiment, e retorna qual o month"*. Somar até um limite é possível, usando `having`, mas retornar qual mês onde parou a soma é que o problema, teria de fazer uma subquery. Se achar um tempo aqui eu tento fazer um exemplo